Redirect .doc to .docx
I have word documents with .doc extension in my hosting files
These files are linked to QR codes. For example, when a QR code is scanned, it goes to this address
https://www.example.com/01-001.doc
QR addresses are physically printed, So I cannot change QR codes. If I change the extensions to .docx it gives a 404 error.
How should I redirect?
I tried this before but it didn't work.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.doc$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.doc$ $1.docx [R=301,L]

My .htaccess file, in public_html folder
RewriteOptions inherit
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.doc$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.doc$ $1.docx [R=301,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# This domain inherits the “PHP” package.
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit


Should work - demo - Are you sure the .docx file actually exists on the server?

And are you sure that you enabled the interpretation of such rules in a distributed configuration file (AllowOverride directive), that the configuration file (".htaccess" file) is located inside the DocumentRoot folder of that http host and that it is readable by the http server process?

Also you need a RewriteEngine on above such a rule.

@arkascha The RewriteEngine On is in the snippet - OP's last edit hid it due to bad markup

I think I understand why it didn't work, but it seemed strange. Before uploading the files, it redirected, but after uploading the files, it didn't redirect

@Tolga "Before uploading the files, it redirected, but after uploading the files, it didn't redirect" - what files are you talking about here? The .doc files? The .docx files?

@CBroe, the .doc files. First i change .htaccess file then i upload .docx files

Then the above is probably not all of your URL rewriting? Sounds like you have conditions & rules before this already, that make decisions based on whether the requested URI matches an existing file or not.

I edited the main topic

The default WP rewriting will rewrite all requests that do not match an existing file or folder, to the index.php. You need to place this before the default WP rewrites.
